# Using CLOB with IN? ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to do this query using IN, but if the type is CLOB doesn't works. 
I need that the parameter p_rut is CLOB and the query I need to use IN, because there it will a select that return more rows to compare.
How can I use parameter CLOB in a IN?

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_TEST (o_dat out o_cursor, p_rut in CLOB)
AS
BEGIN

OPEN o_dat FOR     

select * from cliente
        where rut in (p_rut);

END;
```

The table CLIENTE

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
    PRODUCTO      VARCHAR(50),
    RUT           VARCHAR2(50),
    DV            VARCHAR2(50),
    FONO1         VARCHAR2(50),
    FONO2         VARCHAR2(50),
    FONO3         VARCHAR2(50),
    FONO4         VARCHAR2(50),
    FONO5         VARCHAR2(50),
    FONO6         VARCHAR2(50),             
    COMUNA        VARCHAR2(50),
    EDAD          NUMBER(8),
    SEXO          NUMBER(8),
    DIASMORA      NUMBER(8),
    AÑODEUDA      NUMBER(8),
    PAGOMINIMO    NUMBER(8),
)
;
```

Comment: RUT is varcahr2 (50)  so you are attempting to compare that to a SINGLE clob. No matter how many varchar2 strings you stuff into that SINGLE clob it will remain SINGLE. You need a very different approach.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense regardless of the data type of `p_rut`. What do you **mean** for `p_rut` to be - a comma-separated list of values, and you need to compare `rut` to them?

Comment: It is not clear, why do you need `IN` ? I would understand that `p_rut` needs to be CLOB. But why IN?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DBMS_LOB.INSTR (
   lob_loc    IN   CLOB      CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
   pattern    IN   VARCHAR2  CHARACTER SET lob_loc%CHARSET,
   offset     IN   INTEGER := 1,
   nth        IN   INTEGER := 1)
  RETURN INTEGER;
```

i.e.

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_TEST (o_dat out o_cursor, p_rut in CLOB)
AS
BEGIN

OPEN o_dat FOR     

select * from cliente
        where  DBMS_LOB.INSTR (p_rut,rut)>0;

END;
```

Comment: But this does a different thing. It tests whether `rut` in inside parameter `p_rut`.

Comment: clob is a long string you cannot use with IN, so I assumed you want to see if rut exists at least once within p_rut. Please explain bettter what you are trying to achieve so I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

using IN it can't use CLOB, so I just did a CAST to varchar2.

```
select * from cliente
        where rut in (CAST (p_rut AS VARCHAR2(100));
```